# Does the mere presence of the Google search bar in Firefox mean I'm agreeing to Google's privacy policy?

Tags: firefox, google-search

I just upgraded to FF 10.0.2 and now there's this Google search bar at the top right of my url bar. I'm pretty sure my earlier version of FF didn't have it. Does the mere presence of this Google search bar in FF mean I've agreed to Google's policies?

Comment: The search bar with Google set as default has been a part of Firefox since its initial release in 2004.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, as long as you don't use it, you're fine; if you don't agree with Google's policies, you can change the search bar to have any search engine you want, such as the ones available [in Mozilla's Search Tools](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/search-tools/general).

Comment: There's also an [addon](https://firefox.maltekraus.de/extensions/add-to-search-bar) that allows you to create custom search bar handlers from any search field on any website.